# Validate datatype stored in VARCHAR2 column

Tags: sql, validation, oracle12c

I need to validate datatype and flag if it's NUMBER or DATE.  For e.g. the data in table looks like:

```
COL_VALUE
----------          
'ABC',              
'123',              
'10/23/2024',       
'1/1/2025 10 PM'    
'1/2/2000 10:10:10', 
'100.23'            
'23,33,33.30'
```

I need output something like:

```
COL_VALUE                 IS_NUMBER          IS_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------------
'ABC',                          N               N   
'123',                          Y               N
'10/23/2024',                   N               Y
'1/1/2025 10 PM'                N               Y
'1/2/2000 10:10:10'             N               Y
'100.23'                        Y               N   
'23,33,33.30'                   Y               N
```

So far, I've tried  `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` function, however, I would like to know if there are better ways to accomplish the data type check.

Comment: What would make another approach 'better' - what's wrong with what you are doing now?